# SimpleXML vs DOMDocument with removing nodes

Tags: php, xml, performance, simplexml, domdocument

I have two identical webpages aside from the php code.  One uses SimpleXML and the other uses DOMDocument.  The code edits xml files (reading, adding nodes, removing nodes).

With SimpleXML I must remove nodes using:

```
unset($node);
```

With DOMDocument, however, I use:

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node)
```

While the SimpleXML seems advantageous due to its brevity, it ends up taking an additional 0.4 seconds to load the page that uses SimpleXML (both pages have the same # of php lines).

What is the reason behind this performance difference?  Is it the unset() function that bogs it down?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML is an abstraction on same DOM XML library that the DOM implementation itself uses. But it is an abstraction implemented in C. That means here will be situations where SimpleXML is faster because it combines several actions on the C level and others where it is slower because it just adds syntax sugar.

If you do a lot of manipulations on an XML, using XSLT might be an even faster solution.

Like all optimization you should measure and decide.